# Query to Get Count Value based on Time Interval

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have table just like this :

```
p_central_ticket
================
- t_id              ======>   id ticket
- t_open_by         ======>   name that raise the ticket
- t_closed_by       ======>   name that closed the ticket 
- t_open_time       ======>   open ticket time
- t_closed_time     ======>   closed ticket time
```

How should i do, if i want to show the Count all tickets that closed by name,  and closed time today, weekly, monthly and yearly ? Just like this :

```
    Name                today      weekly     monthly     yearly     
=================================================================   
test1@random.com         2           10          70        1000         
test2@random.com         5           14          60        1234
```

Sample data :

```
t_id      t_open_by      t_closed_by       t_open_time        t_closed_time
===========================================================================
 1     amir@random.com   test1@random.com   2018-03-28          2018-03-29
 2     tiki@random.com   test1@random.com   2018-04-28          2018-05-29
```

Need Help guys...
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some sample data

Comment: i've created sample data, hope you understand it @MuhammadWaheed

Comment: It is possible to get data but i did no find the condition. We can find today but what about week, month ,year(meas its last week - last/current/12 month average month - last/current year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
SELECT `t_closed_by`,
  COUNT( case when `t_closed_time` > curdate() - interval '1' day THEN 1 END ) as today,
  COUNT( case when `t_closed_time` > curdate() - interval '7' day THEN 1 END ) as weekly,
  COUNT( case when `t_closed_time` > curdate() - interval '1' month THEN 1 END ) as monthly,
  COUNT( case when `t_closed_time` > curdate() - interval '1' year THEN 1 END ) as yearly
FROM Table1
GROUP BY `t_closed_by`
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d792/11

Comment: it works. but one thing that i want to ask you, why the first row always appear Null Username with higher total ticket ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below can be used in MySQL: (Note please check the Syntax if there is any error.)

```
SELECT a1.t_closed_by as Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM p_central_ticket WHERE t_closed_time = CURDATE() and t_closed_by = a1.t_closed_by) as today,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM p_central_ticket WHERE t_closed_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and t_closed_by = a1.t_closed_by) as weekly,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM p_central_ticket WHERE t_closed_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and t_closed_by = a1.t_closed_by) as monthly,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM p_central_ticket WHERE t_closed_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) and t_closed_by = a1.t_closed_by) as yearly
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t_closed_by FROM p_central_ticket) a1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get records from the tables with even minutes time interval

```
 SELECT column1,column2,.... FROM tableName
    WHERE
        (DateAndTime BETWEEN '2019-02-11 14:00' AND '2019-02-12 22:00')
    AND
        (DATEPART(MINUTE, DateAndTime) % 60 = 0)
```